# AWS CodeDeploy Most Recent Revision

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, aws-code-deploy

I am using AWS CLI for CodeDeploy. 
CodeDeploy is not deploying the most recent revision, instead it is deploying the last revision I manually deployed.

I have left the version and etag out of my cli command. As per the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-create-cli.html):

> (Optional) The Amazon S3 version identifier for the revision. (If the
>   version identifier is not specified, AWS CodeDeploy will use the most
>   recent version.)

```
aws deploy create-deployment --application-name MyApp --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime --deployment-group-name MyAppGroup --description "My App" --s3-location bucket=MyAppBucket,bundleType=zip,key=MyApp.zip
```

But it is not working. Any ideas? Is there a way to specifically enforce CodeDeploy to use the latest revision?

There is the S3 lifecycle to make sure the older versions are removed, but that is a hack at best. There needs to be an overwrite, or simply a way to force this.

Comment: I found aws deploy list-application-revisions, this always brings the last revision up first, then I parse the json and pass the eTag to the create-application command. This seems very hacky and might not be 100% any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you don't specify the version identifier when creating a deployment, CodeDeploy will try to deploy the latest revision by default according to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-create-cli.html. But do you know how long do you create a deployment after push the new revision to S3?

Thanks,
Binbin

Comment: This is false. You must supply an S3 or Githhub location in the `create-deployment` call.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner for that:

```
aws deploy list-application-revisions \
   --sort-by registerTime --sort-order descending \
   --application-name $MY_APPLICATION_NAME \
   --region eu-central-1 --s3-bucket $MY_BUCKET \
   --query 'revisions[0].s3Location.key' \
   --output text --no-paginate
```

Flags `--sort-by registerTime --sort-order descending` sort the result such that we can parse out the first one easily (see `--query`).

Flags `--output text --no-paginate` returns the result in plain text instead of json. The `--no-paginate` option is required here due to an oddity with the cli to avoid returning the word "None" along with the results.

The `--query` flag parses the result, getting the `key` property of the `s3Location` object which is the first element of the `revisions` array.